# Static method containing object instances, is it wrong?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, static-methods

I'm using an extension method for **string** class. Within that extension method I create an instance of StringBuilder.

Here is the code:

```
    public static string GetPlainTextFromHtml(this string htmlString)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(htmlString);

        foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()"))
        {
            string text = node.InnerText;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                sb.Append(text.Trim());
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

It works but I have a concern regarding memory management.
Static methods don't get instantiated, so what happens if I instantiate an object within static method. Let's say I call this static method 100 times, would there be 100 copies of StringBuilder instances in memory?

Would it cause memory leak? Does Garbage Collector disposes object instance when static method execution terminated?

Comment: `Static methods don't get instantiated` Non-static methods are not instantiated as well. Class instances contain only data. Methods are just called (not instantiated). The difference is that non-static methods are called with class instance, and static methods without class instance.

Comment: @AlexF If an instance is created under a static method, would that not become static by the fact that static methods and properties can not access non-static fields? But if instance of stringbuilder becomes static then how come it is being garbage collected? My head is paining

Answer (score 15):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your code.

Creating instances inside of a static method works the same way as creating instances inside of an instance method. Each call will generate a new instance but will fall out of scope and ready for garbage collection at the end of the method call.

I also don't see anything that implements `IDisposable` so you don't need to worry about cleaning up after yourself there either.

Comment: I can create object instances inside static method. But I was reading  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) microsoft docs and it says we can't: `Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter. ` what this statement means ?

Comment: I came to learn about the same, @justin if you are still active in SO, do you mind throwing light on stom's question

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is perfectly ok to instantiate objects inside static methods. They live within the scope of the method, i.e. when the method returns, they will be marked to be garbage collected (unless you assign them to a field of the parameter or another static field). Yes, for every call to the method, it will instantiate those objects, and that's really what you want it to do; otherwise, multithreading such a method would be a PITA.

If you want to recycle an object, you need to have another static field accessible from the static method that holds the reference. If you use multithreading, at this point you are potentially sharing resources and need to take precautions.

Answer (score 6):

If you call the static method 100 times, each time it will create the `StringBuilder`, perform the work in the method and then return. Once the method is executed and returned, your `StringBuilder` is out of scope and is left for the garbage collector to clean up. So, yes, if you call the method 100 times there will be 100 instances of the `StringBuilder` created - **but each one of them will be disposed of and garbage collected.**

Answer (score 4):

> Static methods don't get instantiated

Methods in general don't get instantiated, so there's no difference in garbage collection between an instance method an a static one.

You might want to read up on how [GC works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) , but a short answer is - no there's no memory leak in this code - local variables will get disposed once GC fires and those are no longer reachable (i.e. in your example the method execution finishes).